# Creating an x509 v3 user certificate by signing CSR

Tags: openssl, certificate, x509, csr, code-signing-certificate

I know how to sign a CSR using `openssl`, but the result certificate is an x509 v1, and not v3.

I'm using the following commands:

```
x509 -req -days 365 -in myCSR.csr -CA myCA.crt -CAkey myCA.key -CAcreateserial -out userCertificate.crt
```

I've searched but have not been able to find a solution. Is there another way to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to specify an extensions file.

For example:

```
openssl x509 -days 365 -in myCSR.csr -extfile v3.ext -CA myCA.crt -CAkey myCA.key -CAcreateserial -out userCertificate.crt
```

The extensions file (v3.ext) can look like this:

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
```

Comment: This might be a good place to say that You can specify the *SAN* (Subject Alternative Names) in the extension file by adding a line: `subjectAltName=DNS:hostname, IP:192.168.7.1`. You can leave out the DNS or IP part, but don't forget to remove the comma then. [More info here](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html).

Answer (score 7):

The answer of gtrig works if you have -req as well. It didn't work without that for me.

So the command is:

```
openssl x509 -req -in myCSR.csr -extfile v3.ext -CA myCA.crt -CAkey myCA.key -CAcreateserial -out userCertificate.crt  -days 365
```

(had to give as a new answer as I don't have enough rep. to comment).