# Chrome on MacOS stopped trusting cert issued by self-signed CA

Tags: macos, google-chrome, ssl

I am running a local development website. The certificate securing it is issued by my own internal certificate authority. I have added the certificate authority to the MacOS keychain and marked it as trusted.

This used to work. Over the weekend, it stopped working. I would love to say that I've changed nothing, but obviously something has changed. Nothing specific comes to mind (perhaps a Chrome auto-update after a restart?)

I am on Chrome Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

I have checked the local site with Opera and Firefox and it loads securely as intended. (I have added the CA cert to the respective trusted roots for each browser). Safari works well too. Only Chrome is giving me grief.

If I look at the developer tools, the security panel is sending mixed messages. It says the cert is valid, but complains that the page is not secure. It is not possible to view the cert:

[image]

Comment: You probably stumbled upon this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715969

Answer (score 0):

@dorian is right. The issue is explained in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=715969 . It was not the TeleText string bug that is described in the beginning. Rather, it was that I had generated a version 1 SSL cert, while it should have been a version 3 cert.

Instructions for creating version3 certs with OpenSSL:

[Creating an x509 v3 user certificate by signing CSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233835/creating-an-x509-v3-user-certificate-by-signing-csr)