# Keytool generate version 3 certificates

Tags: java, ssl, cxf, x509, keytool

Is there way to make keytool generate version 3 certificates?
I'm following this tutorial [Tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/ddmwsst/ws-security-impl/create-server-certificate-and-keystore) and in the end i have version 1 certificates. But then in my application i get exception that is caused by :

```
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Version 1 certificates can't be used as CA ones.
```

I use keytool from jdk8.

EDIT: 
Command

```
openssl x509 -signkey cakey.pem -req -days 3650 -in careq.pem -out caroot.cer -extensions v3_ca
```

changes version of certificate.

Comment: I tried with JDK 8 and JDK8u131, got a v3 certificate with both of them using the same command as in the tutorial. Are you sure its JDK 8 you are using ?

Comment: Path to my keytool is  C:\java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\keytool.exe, so i guess i do. I can try to download exactly same version as you and try it.

Comment: I tried it with JDK8u131 and i still get Version 1 certificates.

Comment: @PallaviSonal Actually i guess that it may not be even problem of keytool or it may be just my machine. In the end ill get into project alredy done keystores but i need some for testing. If you were able to make them in version 3 could you upload them and send link?

Comment: It seems like it is job of the openssl, before i run 
openssl x509 -signkey cakey.pem -req -days 3650 -in careq.pem -out caroot.cer -extensions v3_ca
it is version 3 but after this command version changes to 1.

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @jww Sure, I will add my comment that was above yours  in edit, but according to java code there was nothing bad, this was pure problem of use of openssl x509 command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, it was not problem in keytool, but in openssl changing version.
I needed to specify `-extfile v3.ext` where v3.ext file contained

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
```

according to [thist post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233835/creating-an-x509-v3-user-certificate-by-signing-csr).